Using GRASS GIS addons in QGIS environment
I would like to use r.houghtransform which is an addon to GRASS GIS inside QGIS, because I'm not familiar with GRASS. I have tried to import it with g.extension.manager inside QGIS but it doesn't work for me. Also have tried to copy the source code directly into C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\GRASS8\addons but cant get it to work. Is there anyone who knows how to do it?
